# SAving pictures which needed by my application

Tags: android, download, assets

My app needs to download picture from internet time to time and store them to show when it runs according to the selection. how can i download the pictures and what is the way to store them in my application folder or etc. i m trying to use file output stream on application local folders such as assets and drawable but so far no luck in finding the correct path for it.

Answer (score 0):

To download the images I suggest you use the Apache HttpClient libraries, which are built into the Android SDK.  Here's a tutorial that can get you started quickly with HttpClient:  http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html

To store the images, the following code will get you your app's data directory.  The data directory is located on the device filesystem at `/data/data/your.package.name/files/`.

```
Context ctx = activity.getApplicationContext();
String dataDir = ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
```

If you're interested in storing the images permanently in your user's Gallery, there are APIs for doing that in the `MediaStore` class.

Comment: Thanks, But the thing is i need to download the images to a application local folder and show them in my web view. i can download them to the applications data directory using above way but how can i give the reference to my web views loadDataWithBaseURL() method to load the images from that location. how can i do it?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need to do.  You need to show the images inline with text and other HTML?  If you have a document that references the image as a local file then I guess you should probably be able to use "file:///data/data/your.package.name/files/" as your base URL?  But if you only need to load images then why not just use `ImageView`.